# Is it right to change a primary key of type int to a custom class?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

My C# teacher when declaring a primary key wrote instead of

```cs
public int Id { get; private set; }
```

the following

```cs
public FuelstationId Id { get; set; } = default!;
```

and the needed code

```cs
public record FuelstationId(int Value);
```

a converter

```cs
public class FuelstationIdValueConverter : ValueConverter<FuelstationId, int>
{
    public FuelstationIdValueConverter (ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = null!)
        : base(id => id.Value,
            value => new FuelstationId(value),
            mappingHints)
    { }
}
```

in the DbContext

```cs
builder.Entity<Fuelstation>()
      .Property(f => f.Id)
      .HasConversion(new FuelstationIdValueConverter ())
      .HasColumnName("Id")
      .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
      .IsRequired();
```

Is this really a great way? He just converts it again to a int. Can someone enighten me?

Comment: What did your teacher say when you asked about it?

Comment: "Can someone enighten me?" on what, exactly? There will be pros and cons either way. I suggest you ask your teacher for their reasoning.

Comment: Strongly-typed IDs can be useful, especially when you have a composite key, but they're not necessary. It's a nice-to-have feature, so this is just a matter of opinion.

Comment: @ScottHunter For example, he said the compiler can better handle this and when creating a instance of the object we can't pass the parameters in incorrect sequence like Fuelstation(1,1,4). When we have multiple int properties.

Comment: I am unsure how this affects the compiler. As for passing the incorrect parameters, there are other ways of achieving that, but generally you shouldn't *need* to pass an ID into a DB model. I can't think of any situations where I've done it outside of unit testing or seeding, which you should be extra careful with anyway.

Comment: Great question.  The simple answer is this way is a way to handle the entity, but there are others.  It depends on patterns and how you want to handle things.  What your teacher is doing is following a more Domain Driven Pattern, that could possibly adhere to business rules.  It also offers type safety (no accidental comparisons to other ID's or integers in general), and minimizes any changes to the code if the nature of ID changes (e.g. if ID changes from int to guid, the changes required will be minimal in code).  You can also handle validation or formatting within the value object.